# Combine Print by SQL with different datatype

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here is my SQL from ms-access:

```
SELECT WSID,
       StartDate +' ' + StartTime + ' '+ Duration, + ' ' + Descp as WSP,
       TID
FROM Workshop
```

I'm trying to print out expected result like this:

**11/2/2016 1200 90 WORKSHOP 2**

but since the datatype of startdate is date/time, StartTime is shorttext and duration is shorttext. Once i execute the SQL it get result like this:

[image]

Is this the issue of different datatype? or any solution for this? Thank you

Comment: I fix this type of issues by using `CONCAT(myVariable,'')` which converts `myVariable` to string and appends an empty string. Simple and does the job.

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access, `&` is used for string concatenation.  Remember, `+` can be confused with addition of numbers.  So, I would expect:

```
SELECT WSID,
       (StartDate & ' ' & StartTime & ' '& Duration & ' ' & Descp) as WSP,
       TID
FROM Workshop;
```

Note that I also removed the comma after `Duration` so get three columns in the result set rather than four.